# What is it meant by a normalized eigenfunction and how do you find it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I am doing a course called "Partial Differential Equations" and I was told to "find the normalised eigenfunction for":
$$y''+ \lambda y=0,\;0<x<1$$
subjected to: 
$$y'(0)=0,\;y(1)=0$$
Ok, I know how to work that out. Just need help to understand what exactly makes it normalised. I thought you would check the orthogonal property, but for the second part he said "Verify the orthogonal property of the eigenfuntions." Is there like a condition you use that makes it the normalised version? Eg. finding the values for when $\lambda>0$?

Comment: Normalized means its norm is $1$.  To normalize a vector you divide it by its norm.

Comment: So does that mean normalised version of cos(((2n+1)pi/2)x) is 2cos(((2n+1)pi/2)x)? @littleO

Comment: @littleO, to normalize you divide by the square-root of its norm.  So the normalized version is $\sqrt{2}\cos(...)$

Comment: @Michael forgot to square-root it, so got 1/2 instead of 1/sqr(2).

Comment: @Michael No, to normalize a vector you divide it by its norm, right? Of course the definition of the 2-norm has a square root in it.

Comment: @littleO thats what he did so I guess he made an error in his explanation.

Comment: You divide by the norm. The normalized eigenfunctions are $\cos((2n+1)\pi x/2)/\sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}\cos^{2}((2n+1)\pi x/2)dx}$.